# Query to join with null element

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I use spring data jpa with hibernate.

```
@Entity
public class Samples {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SampleId id;

    @MapsId("samplingId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Samplings sampling;
    ..
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {
    @OneToOne
    private Products product;

    @OneToOne
    private Dimensions dimension;

    @OneToOne
    private Colors color;
    ...
}
```

Dimension and colors could be null.

I search to get `samples` with `product`, `dimensions`, `colors` (if don't have `dimension`, `colors`, want to get `samples` too).

I did :

```
Join<Samples, Samplings> samplings = root.join("sampling", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Samples, Colors> colors = (Join) samplings.join("color", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Samples, Dimensions> dimension = (Join) samplings.join("dimension", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Samplings, Products> product = (Join) samplings.join("product", JoinType.INNER);
```

To get result I need I should put **Left** for `color` and `dimension`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if don't have dimension, colors, want to get samples too

To achieve that, you would need to change the `INNER JOIN`s on `color` and `dimension` to `LEFT JOIN`s :

```
Join<Samples, Samplings> samplings = root.join("sampling", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Samples, Colors> colors = (Join) samplings.join("color", JoinType.LEFT);
Join<Samples, Dimensions> dimension = (Join) samplings.join("dimension", JoinType.LEFT);
Join<Samplings, Products> product = (Join) samplings.join("product", JoinType.INNER);
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to turn the `INNER JOIN` on `product` to a `LEFT JOIN` as well.